# Vuejs is deployed in a server css is but not loaded because of path problem

Tags: vue.js

I have build a vuejs app.It css is working fine with my local system but not working in server .

Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://localhost:51690/a~1540442083/css/app.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' www.canon-europe.com app.gatedcontent.com".

This is the error any one can help

Comment: did you build and upload build files in yiur server?

Comment: Yea .I uploaded the build files

Comment: why the host is localhost when its uploaded in server ?

Comment: if it's build files it won't be the url which you are getting error at. can you share the link where you uploaded?